# I want to handle the exception when database is not connected and should come out of script UNIX

Tags: database, shell, unix, exception

I have made a script which get conneted to database and runs the query.
I want to handle the exception if database is not connected.

Below is my sample code

#!/bin/sh

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/cia/oracle-client/product/11.2.0/client_1

export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8

export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export HOME_DIR=/home/aytripat

```
export OBJECT_TYPE=$HOME_DIR/object_type.txt
export OBJECT_LIST=$HOME_DIR/object_list.txt

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s username/password@dwebpre1  <<EOF
set feedback off heading off pages 4000
spool ${OBJECT_TYPE}
select distinct decode(object_type,'PACKAGE','PACKAGE_SPEC','DATABASE
LINK','DB_LINK','JOB','PROCOBJ',replace(OBJECT_TYPE,' ','_'))from user_objects where object_type not in ('TABLE PARTITION','LOB') order by 1;
spool off
```

Now if sqlplus -s username/password@dwebpre1  <

does not get connected to data base i want it should show exception,and stop there only

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yushi/@deimus

What he meant, is to add an "if" to check the return code. For example:

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "success return"
else
   echo "error"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `$?` return value of your connection command.

Based on its value, handle the "exception" cases.

Comment: @Yushi, check the answer from Enio he did it for me.